# Uncaught ReferenceError: checkLoginState is not defined using facebook API

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, api

I keep trying to fix this code but I am stuck with this error on my console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: checkLoginState is not defined.

I simply followed [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web). Here is my code for this function and when I call it:

```
function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}


<fb:login-button data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" onlogin="checkLoginState();" scope="public_profile, pages_show_list"></fb:login-button>
```

Comment: Simplified code sample or no `<script>`'s tags?

Comment: simplified... its over wordpress i have <script>(function(d, s, id) {

  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;

  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";

  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script> at first on my php page

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}
```

Should be inside your `<script>` block

```
<script>
    function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });
    }

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping facebook sdk in your custom js file,
Keep `checkLoginState()` outside `$(document).ready(function () {});`. That is how it worked for me