# How to use Facebook SDK with Nuxt.js?

Tags: facebook, vue.js, authentication, sdk, nuxt.js

You can see my code.

`npm install vue init nuxt/koa my-project (koa@2)`

pages
|- login.vue

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'login',
  method: {
    login () {
      let vm = this
      FB.login(function (response) {
        vm.statusChangeCallback(response)
      }, {scope: 'publish_actions'})
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    console.log('mounted')
    let vm = this
    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      FB.init({
        appId: 'my-facebook-app-id',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.8'
      })
      FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        vm.statusChangeCallback(response)
      })
    }

    (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }
}
</script>
```

but,

`sdk.js:96 Uncaught TypeError: vm.statusChangeCallback is not a function`

When using the Nuxt project ([nuxt/koa](https://github.com/nuxt/koa)), what is the best way to use the Facebook SDK?

Comment: try just `statusChangeCallback(response)`, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35319801/uncaught-referenceerror-checkloginstate-is-not-defined-using-facebook-api

Comment: Thanks for thanksd. but, Where do I declare this code?

`(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));`

Because, "defined fb" error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs component wait for facebook sdk to load](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38951751/vuejs-component-wait-for-facebook-sdk-to-load)

Comment: I solved it thanks to you. good luck.

Answer (score 13):

I running into the same problem this day. Here is my solution with nuxt.js

First create a plugin `plugins/fb-sdk.js`

```js
const vue_fb = {}
vue_fb.install = function install(Vue, options) {
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return}
        js = d.createElement(s)
        js.id = id
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
        console.log('setting fb sdk')
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))

    window.fbAsyncInit = function onSDKInit() {
        FB.init(options)
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView()
        Vue.FB = FB
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('fb-sdk-ready'))
    }
    Vue.FB = undefined
}

import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(vue_fb, {
    appId: 'your-app-id',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.9'
})
```

We can use `Vue.FB` to invoke methods in FB SDK and listen to the `fb-sdk-ready` event in any component like this:

```js
export default{
    data: function () {
        return {isFBReady: false}
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.isFBReady = Vue.FB != undefined
        window.addEventListener('fb-sdk-ready', this.onFBReady)
    },
    beforeDestroy: function () {
        window.removeEventListener('fb-sdk-ready', this.onFBReady)
    },
    methods: {
        onFBReady: function () {
          this.isFBReady = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

First create a javascript file and include it in your static/js folder:

```
static/js/fb-sdk.js
```

include the script below in your fb-sdk.js file:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
  FB.init({
    appId: '<insert your app id>',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.10'
  })
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView()
};

(function (d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
  if (d.getElementById(id)) { return }
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))
```

Finally in your nuxt.config.js, include the script at the header section:

```js
module.exports = {
  head: {
    title: 'myTitle',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' }
    ],
    script: [
     { src: '/js/fb-sdk.js' }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can now use `window.FB` to execute methods available in FB SDK in your components.

Comment: This should be the better answer, as this is exactly the way suggested by the official Facebook SDK doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart?locale=en_US

Comment: This is the answer, because if you register it as a plugin you will have it loading on every load, instead of only for the desired page.

Answer (score 5):

I used [combined inject][1] to insert the plugin in the context (thus making it accessible in the store):

In `plugins/fb-sdk.js`:

```js
const vue_fb = {}
vue_fb.install = function install(Vue, options) {
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return}
        js = d.createElement(s)
        js.id = id
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
        console.log('setting fb sdk')
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'))

    window.fbAsyncInit = function onSDKInit() {
        FB.init(options)
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView()
        Vue.FB = FB
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('fb-sdk-ready'))
        vue_fb.sdk = FB // do not forget this line
    }
    Vue.FB = undefined
}

import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.use(vue_fb, {
    appId: 'your-app-id',
    autoLogAppEvents: true,
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.9'
})
// and this line
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
inject('fb', vue_fb)
}
```

Making it accessible through `this.$fb`
[1]: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/

Answer (score 2):

A plugin is a good way to inject some feature related logic into Vue instance but, I don't think your Vue instance has to have Facebook login logic all the time. I'd rather go with a `login-with-facebook-button` component like the following fashion;

```html
<template>
  <v-btn v-if="facebookSdkReady" color="primary" dark type="button" @click="login">
    <v-layout mr-2>
      <v-icon name="brands/facebook"/>
    </v-layout>Login with Facebook
  </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'LoginWithFacebook',

  data() {
    return {
      facebookSdkReady: false
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    const installFacebookSdkScript = (d, s, id) => {
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        this.facebookSdkReady = true
        return
      }
      let fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
      let js = d.createElement(s)
      js.id = id
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
    }
    installFacebookSdkScript(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')

    window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
      FB.init({
        appId: '16653216336xxxxx',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v3.2'
      })

      FB.AppEvents.logPageView()
      this.facebookSdkReady = true
    }
  },

  methods: {
    // just a sample code copied from my code base.
    // here, you can replace this with your own.
    async login() {
      const url = await this.$store.dispatch('auth/fetchSocialLoginUrl', {
        provider: 'facebook'
      })

      window.location.href = url
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use [nuxt-auth](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/providers/facebook) it very easy

after install it add to your nuxt-config

```js
auth: {
redirect: {
  login: '/login',
  logout: '/',
  callback: '/callback',
  home: '/'
},
strategies: {
  facebook: {
    endpoints: {
      userInfo: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/me?fields=id,name,picture{url}',
    },
    callback: '/callback',
    clientId: 'YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID', 
    scope: ['public_profile', 'email'],

  },
},
```

then create callback compountent if it needed in your callback compountent you can access facebook data from `this.$route.query;`