# Facebook sdk api subscribed_apps sudden failed with Invariant Violation in nuxt

Tags: facebook, nuxt.js, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbsdk

I've used FB sdk with nuxt for a year now with this guide from:
[How to use Facebook SDK with Nuxt.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665115/how-to-use-facebook-sdk-with-nuxt-js/44932013#44932013)

I tried to use subscribed_apps api (this code works for an entire year, until today)

```js
this.$fb.sdk.api(
  `/${channel.page_id}/subscribed_apps`,
  'POST',
  {
    'access_token': channel.page_token,
    'subscribed_fields':
      'messages, messaging_postbacks, messaging_optins, messaging_handovers, standby, message_echoes, feed, message_reads, messaging_referrals'
  },
  f
)
```

It suddenly failed with error:

```
Invariant Violation: Minified invariant #47458; %s Params: %s
    at a (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=65b90259ffbe513d7eb4969d4ce7450f:67:366)
    at Object._ (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=65b90259ffbe513d7eb4969d4ce7450f:102:180)
    at Object.a [as execute] (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=65b90259ffbe513d7eb4969d4ce7450f:104:1337)
    at u (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=65b90259ffbe513d7eb4969d4ce7450f:105:827)
    at a.w [as graph] (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=65b90259ffbe513d7eb4969d4ce7450f:105:1606)
    at Object.a [as api] (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=65b90259ffbe513d7eb4969d4ce7450f:108:1780)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=65b90259ffbe513d7eb4969d4ce7450f:73:838)
    at Object.api (https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?hash=65b90259ffbe513d7eb4969d4ce7450f:63:260)
    at VueComponent.connectFBChannel (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./components/settings/ConnectAndIntergraton.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:392:22)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1853:26)
```

I checked sdk src from: https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js
There's an update 7 days ago.
And I re-check the api descriptions about params, no update.

I have no clue to debug this at all.
p/s: one more thing, the login endpoint still work fine

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/620565116029656/

Comment: So it's sdk isssue. Thank you so much. I've been struggling for entire day :(

Comment: Probably an update that broke the whole thing.